# JCWDE simulator run: exception from the invoked install() method

Tags: java, javacard, apdu

I am trying to run a jwcde simulation with a hello world applet. I use JC221.

This is the applet:

```
package hello;



import javacard.framework.APDU;

import javacard.framework.Applet;

import javacard.framework.ISO7816;

import javacard.framework.ISOException;

import javacard.framework.Util;



public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet {

         private static final byte[] helloWorld = {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',};



         private static final byte HW_CLA = (byte)0x80;

         private static final byte HW_INS = (byte)0x00;



         public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {

             new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);

         }



         public void process(APDU apdu) {



             if (selectingApplet()) {

             return;

         }



         byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

         byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);

         byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);



         if (CLA != HW_CLA)

        {

            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);

        }



          switch ( INS ) {

             case HW_INS:

               getHelloWorld( apdu );

               break;

            default:

               ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);

         }

   }



  private void getHelloWorld( APDU apdu)

  {

      byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

      short length = (short) helloWorld.length;



      Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(helloWorld, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short) length);



      apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, length);

  }

}
```

I managed to compile it with this command:

```
javac -g -d hello -classpath “.;%JC_HOME%\lib\api.jar;%JC_HOME%\lib\javacardframework.jar” HelloWorldApplet.java
```

And I checked that the compiled class file is on the path.

This is the jcwde.app file that jcwde uses:

```
//+

// Copyright © 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.

// SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.

//-



//+

// Workfile:@(#)jcwde.app    1.4

// Version:1.4

// Date:07/16/03

//-



// applet                                        AID

com.sun.javacard.installer.InstallerApplet       0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0x8:0x1

com.sun.javacard.samples.JavaPurse.JavaPurse     0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0xc:0x2:0x1

com.sun.javacard.samples.JavaLoyalty.JavaLoyalty 0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0xc:0x5:0x1

com.sun.javacard.samples.wallet.Wallet           0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0xc:0x6:0x1

hello.HelloWorldApplet                           0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00:0x01
```

I start jcwde with this command in a command line window (Windows7):

```
jcwde jcwde.app
```

Then I start a new command line window and start apdutool there:

```
apdutool -nobanner -noatr HelloWorldApplet.scr > hello.scr.jcwde.out
```

Here is the .scr script file:
    powerup;

```
// Select the installer applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 0xa0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x08 0x01 0x7F;
// 90 00 = SW_NO_ERROR

// create Applet
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0x0d 0x0b 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x7F;

// Select Applet
0x00 0xa4 0x04 0x00 0x0b 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x6 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x01 0x7F;

// Send APDU command to get a Hello World message
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00;

powerdown;
```

And here is the result (from the jcwde command window):

```
D:\jc221\samples\src\demo\jcwde>jcwde jcwde.app

Java Card 2.2.1 Workstation Development Environment, Version 1.3

Copyright 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.

jcwde is listening for T=0 Apdu's on TCP/IP port 9á025.

Exception from the invoked install() method:public static void hello.HelloWorldApplet.install(byte[],short,byte)

jcwde exiting on receipt of power down command.



D:\jc221\samples\src\demo\jcwde>
```

And this is the result in the hello.scr.jcwde.out file:

```
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00

CLA: 80, INS: b0, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00

CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 0d, 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 01, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 44

CLA: 80, INS: ba, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00

CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 0b, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 00, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00

CLA: 80, INS: 00, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 00, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00
```

So the question is why does it throw exception: Exception from the invoked install() method:public static void hello.HelloWorldApplet.install(byte[],short,byte)

And why is the result SW at the third line SW1:64 SW2:44 and not 90 00 as it should be?

Comment: Please change new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]); to HelloWorldApplet().register()

Comment: @AnuragSharma Why would you ignore the instance AID?

Answer (score 0):

The source of this problem seems to be a bug(?) in JCWDE. While the Java Card specification requires the install parameter to contain at least the length bytes (even for indicating zero length), JCWDE seems to use whatever install parameter it gets through the script. THus, if you don't explcitly pass in installation parameter, the byte array `bArray` will have zero length. Consequently, accessing `bArray[bOffset]` will result in an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception. So it may be a good idea to check the length of `bArray`/`bLength` and call either

```
register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
```

or

```
register();
```

accordingly.